# Iter returning self as a placeholder

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I have seen a lot of examples where the `__iter__` method returns `self`, and I've done my own example:

```
class Transactions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = [1,2,9,12.00]
        self.idx = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        pos = self.idx
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.t[pos]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration

>>> list(iter(Transactions()))
[1, 2, 9, 12.0]
```

How does "returning `self`" make the object iterable? What exactly does that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are making is both an ***Iterator*** and an ***Iterable***. The instances of the `Transactions` class will have both the `__iter__` which makes it an Iterable and `__next__`, which makes it an Iterator.

So when you return `self` from `__iter__` you are basically indicating that the returned object is an Iterable as it has the `__iter__`, and since on calling `__iter__`, it must return an instance of an Iterator therefore you have defined the `__next__` for the same instance so that it behaves like one.

This is highlighted in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

> **Iterable**
>
> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of
>   iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple)
>   and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of
>   any classes you define with an **iter**() method or with a
>   **getitem**() method that implements Sequence semantics.
>        Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (zip(), map(), …). **When an iterable object
>   is passed as an argument to the built-in function iter(), it returns
>   an iterator for the object**. This iterator is good for one pass over
>   the set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not necessary
>   to call iter() or deal with iterator objects yourself. The for
>   statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary
>   unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop.
>   See also iterator, sequence, and generator.
>
> **Iterator**
>
> An object representing a stream of data. **Repeated calls to the
>   iterator’s __next__() method (or passing it to the built-in function
>   next()) return successive items in the stream. When no more data are
>   available a StopIteration exception is raised instead**. At this point,
>   the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to its
>   **next**() method just raise StopIteration again. Iterators are required to have an **iter**() method that returns the iterator object
>   itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be used in most
>   places where other iterables are accepted. One notable exception is
>   code which attempts multiple iteration passes. A container object
>   (such as a list) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it
>   to the iter() function or use it in a for loop. Attempting this with
>   an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used
>   in the previous iteration pass, making it appear like an empty
>   container.

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, defining `__iter__` tells us whether the class is iterable or not; and defining `__next__` actually gives us its iterability. is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, defining the `__next__` makes that object conform to the Iterator protocol, where on calling the `next()` builtin function, retrieves successive elements from the Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

A nice answer was given, I'd like to show a practical example.

The `Transaction` defined in the question is an **iterator**. It can be iterated over just once.

While the typical iteration has the form `for x in ...:`, let's continue to use the shorter `list()` for demonstration:

```
>>> t=Transactions()
>>> list(t)
[1, 2, 9, 12.0]
>>> list(t)
[]
>>> list(t)
[]
```

For a real class, this is not what people expect. In order to iterate over the data every time, a new iterator must be created for each iteration, making the original class an **iterable**:

```
class TransactionsIterator:
    def __init__(self, t): 
        self.t = t 
        self.idx = 0 
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        pos = self.idx
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.t[pos]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration

class Transactions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = [1,2,9,12.00]
    def __iter__(self):
        return TransactionsIterator(self.t)
```

This behaves as other classes usually do:

```
>>> t=Transactions()
>>> list(t)
[1, 2, 9, 12.0]
>>> list(t)
[1, 2, 9, 12.0]
>>> list(t)
[1, 2, 9, 12.0]
>>> list(t)
```

and finally you don't have to reinvent a list iterator, this is all you need:

```
class Transactions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = [1,2,9,12.00]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.t)
```

---

Back to the question. We can iterate over data once with an iterator and every time with an iterable. The whole point of iterators returning `self` in `__iter__` is that the iteration code does not have to distinguish between these two cases.